# Having limits on joined tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Attempting to build a threaded messaging module that allows for multiple recipients. To do this I have a table for recipients, each row contains a message_id and the recipient_id. Below I've created what is essentially a list of a users messages. The code works but because of the way joins are created I get the same message message multiple times if there is more than one recipient which makes it impossible to limit the number of unique messages.

Is it possible to add a limit to the number of messages but still retreive a list of recipients, possibly with another select within the statement?

I guess the php below the the statement shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

```php
$query = mysql_query(

    "SELECT
        messages.message_id,
        messages.message_parent_id,
        messages.message_from_id ,
        messages.message_from_email,
        messages.message_subject,
        messages.message_body,
        messages.message_sent_datetime,

        u_from.forename AS from_forename,
        u_from.surname AS from_surname,

        m_recipients.recipient_user_id AS recipient_user_id,

        u_to.forename AS to_forename,
        u_to.surname AS to_surname

    FROM messages

    INNER JOIN users AS u_from ON messages.message_from_id = u_from.user_id
    INNER JOIN message_recipients AS m_recipients ON messages.message_id = m_recipients.recipient_message_id
    INNER JOIN users AS u_to ON m_recipients.recipient_user_id = u_to.user_id

    WHERE m_recipients.recipient_user_id = 1 OR messages.message_from_id = 1

    ORDER BY messages.message_sent_datetime DESC

    ");

$messages = [];

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))       {

    if (array_key_exists($row['message_id'], $messages)) {
        $messages[$row['message_id']]['to'][] = $row['to_forename'] . ' ' . $row['to_surname'];
    }
    else {
        $messages[$row['message_id']] = [
            'to'       => [$row['to_forename'] . ' ' . $row['to_surname']],
            'from'     => $row['from_forename'] . ' ' . $row['from_surname'],
            'subject'  => $row['message_subject'],
            'body'     => $row['message_body'],
            'datetime' => $row['message_sent_datetime']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `GROUP BY messages.message_id` before `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Sure did but means I only get a maximum of one recipient for each message

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you want. Can you explain what you actually want to return: eg last 5 messages sent by a user with list of recipients for each message sent. My gut feeling is that you need to use GROUP_CONCAT but explain what you want first please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will return you messages with from and to names comma separated.

Is that good enough?

```
    SELECT
    messages.message_id, messages.message_parent_id, messages.message_from_id ,
    messages.message_from_email, messages.message_subject, messages.message_body,
    messages.message_sent_datetime,

    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u_from.forename, ' ', u_from.surname)) as from,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u_to.forename, ' ', u_to.surname)) as to

FROM messages

INNER JOIN users AS u_from ON messages.message_from_id = u_from.user_id
INNER JOIN message_recipients AS m_recipients ON messages.message_id = m_recipients.recipient_message_id
INNER JOIN users AS u_to ON m_recipients.recipient_user_id = u_to.user_id

WHERE m_recipients.recipient_user_id = 1 OR messages.message_from_id = 1
GROUP BY messages.message_id
ORDER BY messages.message_sent_datetime DESC
```

You may want to play with GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT )

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what was after, first time using group_concat.

I made a couple of amendments:

    CONCAT(u_from.forename, ' ', u_from.surname) as from_x,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u_to.forename, ' ', u_to.surname)) as to_x

because from is reserved by mysql and i didnt need to group the from column as theres only ever one sender. thanks again